# Python pandas filter data by groupby second level values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a groupby object with two groups (Time & Region).  I need to plot the values of each region by time.  Before plotting I figured I would create a dataframe of each region but I'm having trouble extracting all of the Times for a specific region - for example filter out all regions except for those with a value of 2.  I would have thought something like "group_df.region == 2".

I have lots of trouble working with multi-index / groupby objects in general - any direction would be greatly appreciated.

An example:

```
import random
times = range(0,11)
regions = range(1,6)
vals = []
for t in times:
    for r in regions:
        vals.append( [t,r,random.randint(1,100)] )
    

df_gp = df.groupby(['time','region'])

df_gp.mean().head(10)


             value
time region       
0    1          53
     2          98
     3          41
     4           4
     5          62
1    1          34
     2          40
     3          35
     4          49
     5          36
```

I want to get the mean of all region 2 data, thinking something like:

```
df_gp[[df_gp.region==2]]
```

Instead I iterate over the times and use get_group to append values to a new array that I then create a new dataframe from.  Seems a bit to much of a work around to me.

```
gs = []
for t in times:
    gs.append(df_gp.get_group((t,2)).mean()) #I need mean value for each region at that time
    
print(gs)
```

Make an array with just the time and values:

```
tv = [ (g.time, g.val) for g in gs]
```

Make a new dataframe for region 2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tv,columns=['time','vals'])
```

Plot:

```
df2.plot(x='time',y='vals')
```

Aside from my workaround above, I can also filter out the dataframe by region BEFORE creating the groupby.  I like the idea of groupby('time','region') but can't seem to interface with that object as I would expect.   Thanks.

```
df[df.region==2].groupby('time').mean()
```

Any direction here would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Groupby doesn't exactly let you do that. The alternative solution ``df[df.region==2].groupby('time').mean()`` works perfectly fine - what does it not do for you?

Comment: `df.mean(level=1)`?

Comment: It seems to make logical sense (for me at least) to group the data by time and region and then use it as needed.    I guess groupby is just limited in it's ability to select data by deeper level groups.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to filter the data before grouping:

```
df[df.region==2].groupby('time').mean()
```